# Calculating the limit $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \prod\limits_{i=1}^{k}(1-\alpha_i+\alpha_i^2)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How do I evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty} \prod_{i=1}^{k}(1-\alpha_i+\alpha_i^2)$?

Here, $\alpha_k\in (0,1)$ for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\alpha_k=0$.

Comment: The result will clearly depend in the sequence... (if you pick any sequence $(\beta_k)_{k\geq1}$ such that all its terms are in $(0,1]$ and such that the product $\prod_{k\geq1}\beta_k$ converges to $P$, there is a unique sequence $(\alpha_k)_{k\geq1}$ with $\alpha_k\in[0,1/2)$, $\beta_k=1-\alpha_l+\alpha_k^2$, $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\alpha_k=0$ and therefore $\prod_{k\geq1}(1-\alpha_l+\alpha_k^2)=P$.

Comment: Moreover, in order for the limit to be nonzero you need $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\alpha_n - \alpha_n^2)$ to converge.

Comment: Thank you for all your interesting comments. Please help me to give a complete solution of this problem.

Comment: What Robert said is about all you can say without additional information on $a_i$.

Comment: Dear Robert. Thank you in advance for your comments. I want to know where we can find the fact you said.

Comment: Deat Robert. Can you give me a proof of your statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit of the products $\prod\limits_{i\leqslant k}(1-\alpha_i+\alpha_i^2)$ when $k\to\infty$ is a nonnegative number in $[0,1)$, which is positive if and only if the sum of the series $\sum\limits_k\alpha_k$ is finite.

**Edit:** The WP page on [infinite products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product) might prove useful and, to begin with, the first section on [convergence criteria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Convergence_criteria).

Once this is ingested, one can come back to the question here. Consider $\beta_k=\alpha_k-\alpha_k^2$. For every $\alpha_k$ in $(0,\frac12)$, $\beta_k\leqslant\alpha_k\leqslant2\beta_k$. Since $\alpha_k\to0$ by hypothesis, this proves that the series $\sum\limits_k\alpha_k$ converges if and only if the series $\sum\limits_k\beta_k$ does.

Comment: How can we prove this fact?

Comment: I am confused: should I answer you here or [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/121348/6179)? *Cruel, terrible, insoutenable dilemne*...

Comment: Thank you in advance for your comments. I am waiting the reply from you. Could you give me some references related to your fact?

Comment: See Edit. (But to call any of this *my fact* is inappropriate.)